# Nuxt Menu links from API...How can i detect if its a Nuxt link :to or :href?

Tags: api, vue.js, menu, nuxt.js, href

Im building my main menu from an API :

```
  <b-navbar-nav>
        <div v-for="result in resultsmenu" :key="result.id">
       <span class="hoverlink">
  <nuxt-link  :to="result.slug">{{result.title}}</nuxt-link>
    </span>
     </div>
      </b-navbar-nav>
```

Everythings works well but one problem is in the menu from the API ..One link is external with an "href" like : https://ww.instagram.com so nuxt-link process it like a internal route i end up with :

http://localhost:3000/https://ww.instagram.com

I was wondering if there is a way to tell Nuxt that if a link is an "href" type: "link" to handle it like an external link instead of an nuxt-link to: ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use a computed property.

Assuming your `resultsmenu` data looks something like...

```
resultsmenu: [
  {slug: 'http://www.website.com', title: 'link to website.com'},
  {slug: '/test', title: 'link to a website.com'},
  {slug: '/yay', title: 'link to b website.com'},
  {slug: 'http://www.website.com', title: 'link to c website.com'}
]
```

You can do...

```
computed: {
  menuLinks() {
    let links = []
    this.resultsmenu.forEach(link => {
      let menuItem = {}
      menuItem.isHttp = !!link.slug.includes('http');
      menuItem.target = link.slug
      menuItem.title = link.title
      links.push(menuItem)
    })
    return links
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<div v-for="(result, index) in menuLinks" :key="index">
  <span>
    <nuxt-link v-if="!result.isHttp" :to="result.target">{{result.title}}</nuxt-link>
    <a v-else :href="result.target">{{result.title}}</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Super... Thank you :)  i will try this one tonight :)

Comment: No problem! I could add to this answer, I usually try to do this sort of thing in the backend (tag the links with “isHttp” for example) before returning the data to the frontend. That way you’re not worrying about manipulating the data on the frontend— you’re just presenting it to the user, throwing in the occasional 'v-if' etc.

Comment: It works super well Thanks again @NickDawes :) i will use this one on all my future website